# How to get keys of a field in a document in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    'id': 123,
    'somekey': {
        'x': [],
        'y': [],
        'z': [],
    }
}
```

I want to get the result as:
 `['x', 'y', 'z']`. What is the relevant query to achieve this?

Comment: perhaps using `mapReduce`.

Comment: mapReduce works only on keys of the document. But in this case 'x', 'y', 'z' are variable

Comment: What do you mean by *'x', 'y', 'z'* are variables? can you please elaborate?

Comment: i have confused myself. Sorry i found the right answer. Thanks @user3100115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant query is through **[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/map-reduce/)**. The following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection with all the keys of the `somekey` subdocument as the `_id` values:

```
var map = function() {
        for (var key in this.somekey) { 
            emit(key, null); 
        }
    },
    reducer = function(key, stuff) { return null; }, /* or do reducer = function(key, stuff) { } since it's not doing anything */
    mapreduce = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce": "collectionName",
        "map": map,
        "reduce": reducer, 
        "out": "someKeyCollectionKeys"
    });
```

You can get a list of all the dynamic subdocument keys by running distinct on the resulting collection:

```
db[mapreduce.result].distinct("_id")
```

**Output**

```
[ "x", "y", "z" ]
```

Comment: You can do `reducer = function(key, stuff) { }`  since it's not doing anything

Comment: @user3100115 Cheers for the suggestion! :)